# Lift with db4o User model

Tags: scala, db4o, lift

suppose you have a **Lift + db4o** project... How do you define **User model**? Should I extend **MetaMegaProtoUser**?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to Extend the MetaMegaProtoUser:

```
class User extends MetaMegaProtoUser[User] { 
...
}
```

It handles all the stuff related to user registration, password change etc..